# How to prevent appending to the same element

Tags: jquery, font-awesome-5

im not extremely familiar with jquery but im having some issues with appending. Here is my code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".add-row").addClass('btn w3-teal');
        $(".add-row").append("<i class='fas fa-plus'></i>");
        $(".delete-row").addClass('btn w3-teal float-right');
        $(".delete-row").append("<i class='fas fa-minus' id = no></i>");
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".add-row").click(function(){
        $(".delete-row").addClass('btn w3-teal float-right').append("<i class='fas fa-minus' id = hi></i>");
        $(".select2-selection").css({"width":"100%"});
        $(".modelselect2").css({"width":"100%"});
        $(".delete-row").append("<i class='fas fa-minus' id = hi></i>");
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".delete-row").click(function(){
        console.log($(".modelselect2"));
        $(".modelselect2").css({"width":"100%"});
    });
</script>
```

everytime i click on the add-row button , it appends to my previous delete-row button. I have tried many ways to prevent htis from happening but have failed to do so , does someone have a solution?

Comment: `$(".delete-row").last().append()` ?  Though keep in mind you're duplicating ids with the `id=hi`, which is missing quotes around it

Comment: Curious why you have 3 separate `script` blocks. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: share your html than we can have better look at your problem

Comment: yes sorry the reason why i didnt show it is because what im using this for is actually a formset.html for a dynamic inline form . Which has different styling methods than conventional html , putting the .last() solved my issue, thank you so much for your time!